# How do I remove the apps "Files" and "File Manager"?

Tags: 14.04, software-uninstall

About a year ago "Files" and "File Manager" started to act very strangely and all my files were lost, despite an extensive search. Two days later I lost all my data and files from my SATA hard-drive. Luckily I had a backup, but "Files" continued to lose everything every time I put removable media into the USB slots.

Frustrated with "Files" and "File manager" I installed "Thunar" which was an instant success. However "Files" is still set as the default manager for removable media and Rubbish Bin.

Today "Files" moved the contents of my terrabyte SATA drive into the Rubbish Bin and changed the permissions, which prevented me from restoring the contents back onto the drive with "Thunar". In the end I had to copy the folders onto my desktop, rename them and put them back that way.

I want to remove "Files" and "File Manager" but they cannot be un-installed in either "Software Centre" or the Dashboard. I cannot make "Thunar" open the removable media or the rubbish bin as "Files" must be the default for these operations. Is there any way of using terminal to remove these apps as they seem to be standard as part of the Ubuntu package

Comment: "I want to remove "Files" and "File Manager" but they cannot be un-installed in either "Software Centre"". You can through command line but it is unlikely that that is your problem. Nautulis in itself does nothing. Unless you have dubious scripts running I'd assume something else is goign on.

Comment: I flagged this as duplicate, but I'm not sure the solution will fix your underlying issue. Nautilus shouldn't behave the way you're describing, so maybe there is something else going on - maybe malware.

Comment: I also suspected an underlying issue and have since removed 14.04 and re-installed it.  This solved the issue but I prefer Thunar now and installed it and used the suggestion b from @Mina Michael which worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally files is just `nautilus` so if you want to remove it maybe you have to execute

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nautilus
```

but I have a bad feeling about it. Nautilus is deeply integrated within ubuntu.

---

Anyway I found a [community help wiki that has methods to set Thunar as default file manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager). There's a script method and there's a manual method.

The script method should be easier however there's a disclaimer written before it. *(I don't think you should worry)*

To use the script method anyway make a text file in your home folder and name it `defaultthunar` then copy [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Script_to_change_Thunar_to_be_the_default_file_manager) script and paste it inside the text file.

Then run those two commands:

```
chmod +x defaultthunar
./defaultthunar
```

That's it. If you want to restore back nautilus run `./defaultthunar` in terminal (which just runs the script again).

Alternatively you can do the [manual method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Changing_Your_Default_File_Manager) if you want.

Comment: I suspected an underlying issue and removed 14.04 and re-installed it.  This solved the issue but I prefer Thunar now and installed it and used the suggestion you made. No issues since.

Comment: okay gr8! then click the "tick" mark that's to the left of this answer ;) @user355507

Comment: Also if I may leave a suggestion PCManFM is my favorite files manager, I recommend giving it a try